# Showing something for 120 seconds

Tags: php, session

I need to show something on all pages on a site for 120 seconds after the user hits the site

I am setting a session up with

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['phonecookie'])){
    $_SESSION['phonecookie'] = array("expire"=>time()+60*2);
}
```

then to display the content I am using this on all of the pages.

```
session_start(); //if not already called with the above statement

if(isset($_SESSION['phonecookie']['expire'])){
    if($_SESSION['phonecookie']['expire'] >= time()){
        echo "the content";
    }
}
```

for some reason on refresh of a page it keeps changing the value of the phonecookie session value even though I am only generating the phonecookie session value if it doest exist.

Comment: Is it using the same session on each request? Or is it creating a new session everytime? Output your sessionId to see if it changes between requests.

Comment: its changing the session every time on my live server but on my local server it uses the same session id

Comment: Then there's your problem, if the session id changes on your live server, you need to make sure that it re-use the previous session. Read more about that in '[Passing the Session ID](http://dk2.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) section in the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isset()` checks whether a variable exists. `$_SESSION` behaves like an array. I would advise to use one of these:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['phonecookie']['expire']) {}
```

or

```
if (array_key_exists('expire', $_SESSION['phonecookie'])) {}
```

Comment: isset() also works with arrays... check the second example on the doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Thanks Christian, its still doing the same thing though and not workign as expected?